# Spring boot with jpa + querydsl

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Caused by: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using incorrect annotation for @Repository base class